# Problems with ListCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

This is my `ListCellRenderer`:

```
public class MyListCellRendererOTP extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            Component cell = null;

            if (value instanceof Domain) {
                Domain domain = (Domain)value;
                int status = domain.getStatus();
                String naziv = domain.getNaziv();
                int naziv1= domain.getId();
                String naziv2=naziv+"  "+naziv1;
                ArrayList<Stavka> s=domain.getStavke();
                int nasao=0;
                for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++){
                    if(s.get(i).getTrazKol()!=s.get(i).getIzdKol()){nasao=1;}
                }

                cell = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list,naziv2,index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                if(nasao==1){
                    cell.setBackground(Color.cyan);
                }else{
                    cell.setBackground(Color.white);
                }
                if(isSelected){
                    cell.setBackground(Color.green);
                }
            }
        return cell;
    }
  }
```

I have a `Jlist` that is populated with Domains.  The idea is for renderer to change background of rows where certain fields of `Domain` class are different, as shown in the code. But this is not working for some reason. Every row gets affected. Can anyone help?

Comment: JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus are parameters from underlaying XxxModel,

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: my bad people... as its stands (float != float) is a no noo :)) as much as i can tell that was causing problems. thanks everyone

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Comment: wasn't even aware that i am able to do that...that doesn't sound nice, i am more on the lines of being sorry for wasting your time.